# Feature Request: udp server with netty: create a channel for each remote address

Tags: netty

***ConnectionlessBootstrap*** creates a single Channel on bind.
The same channel is used upstream for all incoming messages from all remote addresses and downstream for outgoing messages. Therefore the same pipeline object is used.

***ServerBootstrap*** creates a new channel for each remote address when it connects and therefore a new pipline is created.

It is desirable that ConnectionlessBootstrap  create a new channel for each remote address. This will allow one to use "channel specific handlers" such as ChannelTrafficShapingHandler or OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor. This channel should be used for all incoming/outgoing message to the same remote address.

One could then also use channel.write() without the remote address, making it easier to port tcp applications to udp.

Since we do not have a disconnect, the channel could be closed using a ReadTimeoutHandler.

Currently if one needs the function of these handlers it has to be reimplemented "outside of the pipline" where data is stored in remote address specific objects.

What do you think ?

-- Ron

Comment: Would love to have this feature. I have written a game server(https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) using netty and lack of this feature really bothered me.

Comment: How about using LocalChannel classes and placing a kind of Mux/Demux channel handler as the single handler for the UPD socket?

Comment: Following up at https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/344